# Conversion de fecha guardada en formato date('d-m-Y')

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy guardando en mi Base de Datos la *fecha* del registro en un *campo* llamado *Fecha*, el `input` es de tipo `date`. Resulta que el dato se está guardando de la siguiente manera `2017-11-28`, eso es lo de menos, el problema surge en que debo y quiero mostrar ese dato en mi sitio web de la siguiente manera:

*Resultado deseado:*

`Viernes, 24 / Noviembre / 2017`

La pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo convertir esa fecha al formato que necesito?

*Mi código:*

```
//Fecha
$fecha = '2017-11-25';
//Imprimo.
echo $fecha;
```

Saludos.

Comment: leete esto, http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php
con date también se podría pero solo en ingles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`strftime`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strftime.php) — Formatea una fecha/hora local según una configuración local.

[`setlocale`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.setlocale.php) — Establecer la información del localismo.

**Un posible ejemplo:**

```
//Establecer la información del localismo.
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES'); 
//Tu fecha
$fecha = '2017-11-25';
//Imrimimos fecha con la función `strftime`.
echo utf8_encode(strftime("%A, %d de %B de %Y", strtotime($fecha))) . ".\n";
```

*Resultado*: `Sábado, 25 de Noviembre de 2017`.

> **Nota:** si deseas usar la barra `/` simplemente debes cambiar las palabras `de` `"%A, %d / %B / %Y"`.

*formatos usados*:

- `%A`     Una representación textual completa del día     domingo hasta sábado
- `%d`     El día del mes con dos dígitos (con ceros iniciales)    01 a 31
- `%B`     Nombre del mes completo, basado en el localismo     enero hasta
  diciembre
- `%Y`     Representación de cuatro dígitos del año    Ejemplo: 2038

Comment: Gracias D.Bulten me ha funcionado. Saludos.